# Dividing 3 different numbers to get different related remainders

Tags: contest-math, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Here is the question, from the 2013 Division A mathletes competition in Illinois. I'm doing this for practice for my test and I've seen this come up more than once:

Find the largest integer that divides $300$, $417$, and $764$ with remainders $R_1$, $R_2$, and $R_3$, respectively, such that $R_2=R_1+3$ and $R_3=R_2+5$.

Answer (score 2):

So you want
\begin{align}
117=417-300= 3 \mod n\\
347=764-417 = 5\mod n
\end{align}
where $n<300$. Hence $n \mid  114$ and $n \mid 342$. Since
\begin{align}
114= 2\cdot 3\cdot 19 \ \ \text{ and } \ \ 342= 2\cdot 3^2\cdot 19
\end{align}
then $n=2\cdot 3 \cdot 19=114$ is the greatest common divisor.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not know about that operation entirely. Totally opened up the problem!